# Create new instance from singleton

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

## Intro:

I have some legacy code that creates a singleton:

```
define(['backbone', 'MyModel'], function (Backbone, MyModel) {

  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    initialize: function () {
      //...
    }
  });

  return new MyCollection();
});
```

And for test purposes I need to generate new instances to inject them as dependeces.

## Question:

Is there any way to generate new instances of the singleton without modifying the original code?

## What I've done:

I came with a solution: add the class as a property of the instace

```
    initialize: function () {
      this.ClassObject = MyCollection;
      //...
    }
```

and then instantiate it

```
var myCollection = require('myCollection');
var myCollectionInstance = new myCollection.ClassObject();
```

This solution modifies the class and I'd like to avoid it.

I also tryed creating a copy of the singleton:

```
function generateNewCollection() {
  var F = function () {};
  F.prototype = myCollection;
  return new F();
}
```

It generates a new instance but it doesn't create new instances of its dependences, so the environment is still dirty for the next tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: use the constructor function from the prototype.

```
var newMyCollection = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(myCollection).constructor);
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the class definition as a property of the instance is the only way I've ever found to solve this. You may want to standardize on `Klass` as the property name, that seems to be the way folks are going. The solution might feel a bit dirty, but it has worked really well at least for me.

Another enhancement, since I notice you're using a module pattern, is to have the module return an instance. This way it manages the singleton pattern for you, since it will only include each dependency once.

Here is what that looks like:

```
define ['models/sprockets'],(Sprocket) ->
  MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend
    model: Sprocket
    initialize: -> console.log 'initialized'
  myCollection = new MyCollection()
  myCollection.Klass = MyCollection
  return myCollection # If managed by requireJs or curl, this module will always return you the same singleton and will have the class available on the `Klass` property
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'll try to avoid modifying the original code of the module, and the enhancement you coment is the one that's causing my problems: `return new MyCollection();`. I'd love to have a class with a method `getInstance` instead of only the instance. With that I could get the instance, generate new instances with the class or modify the `getInstance` method to return new instances so in all tests there whould be new instances without injection. And please, try not to use coffe-script when asnwering a javascript question.

Comment: Haha. CoffeeScript is the future, ya'll. I wasted too much of my Javascript career not using it. Time to get on board.

Comment: I'm not against CoffeeScript; I'm against _answering JS questions in Coffee_.

Comment: @SimplGy it didn't happen mate